# How to use HyperTerminal for HC-05 Bluetooth module using USB to UART converter on laptop without any external MCU boards

Tags: bluetooth

I'm working on a project to stream audio from a Smartphone or Bluetooth enabled device to Bluetooth receiver with a speaker or headphone.

So I started with HC-05 Bluetooth Module as a Bluetooth receiver, for receiving audio and connected it to a speaker or headphone. But the HC-05 module is not responding to Hyperterminal Communication.

I then connected the Bluetooth module to a laptop (running with Windows 7) using a USB-to-UART converter. But the AT commands I'm sending are not working. I get nothing in response on hyperterminal.

I configured Hyperterminal to use 38400 BAUD rate, no parity, no flow control, 8 bit data and 1 stop bit. I tested the USB-to-UART converter and it is working.

So I'm wondering:

1. **How can I make AT commands work for this on hyperterminal?**
2. **How should I program this module for adding profiles on flash memory?**
3. **Is it possible to receive stream audio with this device?**

Comment: Don't use Hyperterminal, it is broken by design, some (undocumented) key strokes are not copied to the serial interface. A better alternative is [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty).

Answer (score 1):

The default baud rate for the HC-05 is 9600 bps. Setup your Hyper terminal to 9600 baud rate, no parity, no flow control, 8 bit data, and 1 stop bit.

Comment: even for 9600 it is not working

Comment: now its working with at commands at 38400 baud rate.but how to stream audio through serial port profile

Answer (score 0):

I think HC 05 module is meant for just sending/receiving data (as it supports only SPP ). If you want to stream audio you need to use bluetooth modules which supports A2DP or other audio profiles.

Answer (score 0):

in bluetooth model HC-05 and to start work in AT command, need to put 34 pin of bluetooth to high, i did this by connect 34 pin of bt to arduino digital pin, and before put this pin to high, need to power bt first and then put 34 to high. This way i did to enter AT command. by the way, the default baud rate of hc-05 is 38400 and the termainal used suppose be same baud rate.